# Retain the ../../../ in wget command

Tags: bash, directory, wget, url

`../../../` is removed when i use it with the url in `wget` command. PLease see below:

```
user $ wget http://n0t.meaning.anything:20000/../../../some/folder/file
--2015-10-29 16:48:13--  http://n0t.meaning.anything:20000/some/folder/file
Resolving n0t.meaning.anything (n0t.meaning.anything)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘n0t.meaning.anything’
user $
```

You can ignore second and third line (because the url actually doesnt exist). But in the first line you see:

```
--2015-10-29 16:48:13--  http://n0t.meaning.anything:20000/some/folder/file
```

But my command was

```
wget http://n0t.meaning.anything:20000/../../../some/folder/file
```

So you can see that `../../../` was dropped by my shell (or by the wget command).

How do I retain the `../../../` in wget command.

Comment: i don't think that `http://foo/../bar` is actually a valid URL...

Comment: @umläute: RFC1808 5.2 suggests it is an abnormal case but the `..` should not be dropped in the way one might think is obvious. I doubt existing software handles it like that, though, they just implicitly treat the root directory as its own parent and drop the `..` like the OP observes.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz It's worth noting that it has been superseded by RFC 3986, it's stance on is this here is the same though (AFAIK).

Comment: @phk: Good point, I only checked very briefly (because it sounds like the kind of thing that nobody remembers is actually in the spec).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can without URL-encoding them. `wget`'s `src/url.c` removes them; as far as I can tell from a *very* brief look at the source there's no way around it.

```
/* Resolve "." and ".." elements of PATH by destructively modifying
   PATH and return true if PATH has been modified, false otherwise.

   The algorithm is in spirit similar to the one described in rfc1808,
   although implemented differently, in one pass.  To recap, path
   elements containing only "." are removed, and ".." is taken to mean
   "back up one element".  Single leading and trailing slashes are
   preserved.

   For example, "a/b/c/./../d/.." will yield "a/b/".  More exhaustive
   test examples are provided below.  If you change anything in this
   function, run test_path_simplify to make sure you haven't broken a
   test case.  */
```

Answer (score 2):

[RFC3986 §5.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4.2) (thanks @phk) states:

> Parsers must be careful in handling cases where there are more ".."
> segments in a relative-path reference than there are hierarchical
> levels in the base URI's path.  Note that the ".." syntax cannot be
> used to change the authority component of a URI.
>
> ```
>  "../../../g"    =  "http://a/g"
>  "../../../../g" =  "http://a/g"
> ```

The above examples use base URI `http://a/b/c/d;p?q`.

`http://a/b/c/d/../../../../g` (the 2nd example) is equivalent to `http://a/../g`, which (according to the RFC) must be resolved as `http://a/g`.

So the URI parser of `wget` (and `firefox` for that matter) is correct in stripping the leading `../` components